# Standardising third moment

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, variance, means, standard-deviation

I am assigning values to objects in a process. I would like the values to end up being normally distributed with variance one. For this I standardise them by subtracting their average from each and dividing by the standard deviation. Thus they end up with "normal" mean and variance. But they tend to have a large skewness. I can calculate their skewness, but what do I do with it? What operation is necessary to apply to the values with regard to skewness so that they are not skewed? (I am guessing it is either logarithm or root.)

EDIT: I am looking for a formula to apply to the values that takes the skewness into account and makes it zero.

Comment: You can't necessarily transform univariate sample data so that it is normally distributed. However to remove skewness in the sample, there are various transforms of the data you can use (e.g. log transform); see https://medium.com/@TheDataGyan/day-8-data-transformation-skewness-normalization-and-much-more-4c144d370e55

Comment: I would call $z_i = \frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}$ *standardising* rather than *normalising*

Comment: Thanks. Calling it standardising now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a random variable $X$ has a continuous cumulative distribution function $F$, you can transform it into $f(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ by considering $f(x)=\Phi^{-1} \circ F(x)$, where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for details. Of course, in practice $F$ is not known, but you can replace it by the empirical cumulative distibution function $\widehat{F}$. Then $\widehat{F}(X_{(1)})=1/n$ for the smallest value $X_{(1)}$ in your sample,  $\widehat{F}(X_{(2)})=2/n$ for the second smallest value $X_{(2)}$, etc. (note that if you do this, you will have to discard the largest value in your sample because $\Phi^{-1}(1)$ is not defined or would be $+\infty$).

Comment: I don't think this is very robust. What if I randomly sample a lot of similar values. They will mess up the empirical cdf.

Comment: Also I am actually more interested if there is a similar method to the ones I mentioned. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Marked as solution, as this kind of solves my problem. Was interested in a more direct approach though.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry that it did not really answer what you were looking for. An idea that could work but seems also a bit cumbersome would be to let $Y = a + b X + cX^2$ and find $(a,b,c)$ so that $E(Y)=E(Y^3)=0$ and $E(Y^2)=1$.